# How to find a string element in one of several arraylists inside a list?? C#

Tags: c#, list, search, edit

I'm struggling with arraylists within a list. Got a few questions.

First of all: My trials with removing a logg is working but i trigger an exception, don't know what to do (see case 4).

Second: I'm suppose to be able to edit to any of the existing logs (not in menu yet), more like change one of the strings in an existing log like "post" or "title. Can anyone give me a hint??

```
{
    List<string[]> logBook = new List<string[]> { }; // Skapar en lista för arrayer av typen string.
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;  // Sätter variabeln time till lokal tid på datorn.

    int logCount = 0;  // Deklarerar en variabel för att räkna inläggen,
                       // läggs utanför case 1 så att den är nollad vid uppstart av programmet 
                       // och när den kommer in i case 1 så räknar den upp.

    Console.WriteLine("\t" + time.ToLongDateString()); // Skriver ut datum i ett passande format för en loggbok.
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the Logbook!\n");  // Skriver ut välkomsttext en gång vid uppstart,
                                                         // därför läggs den utanför while-loopen.

    bool go = true; // Booleanskt värde för while-loopen som ska ligga för menyn och som br

    while (go)
        try         // Exception-block som fångar upp om användaren knappar in ex. bokstäver som val i menyn (förhindrar körfel).
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");  //Skapar ny rad. Användaren ska inte känna att det blandar ihop sig.
                Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Write a new post");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Search for a post");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Display all posts");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Remove a post");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[5] Quit");

                Console.Write("\n\tSelect from menu: ");

                int menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Gör om inmatad sträng till heltal.
                Console.WriteLine("");  //Skapar mellanrum innan nästa direktiv till användaren (Estetiskt).

                switch (menu)
                {
                    case 1:

                        logCount++;
                        string logNr = "Log number: " + logCount.ToString();  // Skapar en nurering av loggarna.

                        string timeDate = time.ToLongDateString();  // Ger oss ett datum för inlägget.

                        Console.Write("\tWrite a title to your post: ");
                        string title = "Title: " + Console.ReadLine();  // Ger oss en titel för inlägget.

                        Console.Write("\n\tPost is created " + timeDate + "\n\n\tWrite your post: ");

                        string post = Console.ReadLine();

                        string[] arr = new string[4];
                        arr[0] = logNr;  
                        arr[1] = timeDate;
                        arr[2] = title;
                        arr[3] = post;

                        logBook.Add(arr);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("\tWrite a searchword or a date (yyyy-mm-dd): ");
                        string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        bool anyFound = false;

                        foreach (string[] item in logBook)  //För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
                        {
                            foreach (string element in item)  //För varje element(element) i arr[i] dvs (arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
                            {
                                if (element.Contains(keyword))  // Om arr[0], arr[1] eller arr[2] innhåller sökord....,
                                                                // letar efter en substring(keyword) inom strängen.
                                {
                                    foreach (string s in item)  // Skriv ut varje arr[i] i det elementet(item) (dvs hela den loggen)
                                                                // I detta fall tre varv, datum, titel, text(post) = 3 strängar.
                                                                // För att användaren ska kunna se hela loggen som sökordet finns i.
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + s);
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine("");
                                    anyFound = true;  // Kliver ur loopen då uppdraget är slutfört, bool ändrar värde till true.
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!anyFound)  // Om inget hittas dvs bool är fortfarande oförändrat genomförs utskrift.
                            Console.WriteLine("\tSearchword couldn't be found.");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("\tThese are the current posts in Logbook.\n ");

                        foreach (var item in logBook)  //För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
                        {
                            foreach (string element in item)  //För varje element(element) i arr[i] dvs (arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\t" + element);
                            }
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4:

                        Console.Write("\tWhich log number do you want to remove? : ");
                        string erase = "Log number: " + Console.ReadLine();

                        foreach (string[] item in logBook)  // För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
                        {
                            if (item.Contains(erase))  // Om arr[0], arr[1] eller arr[2] innhåller sökord....,
                            {
                                logBook.Remove(item);  // raderas hela elementet(item/arr[i])
                                Console.WriteLine("\t" + erase + " is now removed from logbook.");
                            }
                        }


                        break;

                    case 5:
                        go = false; // Avbryter while-loopen och med det avslutar programmet.
                        break;

                    default:        // Fångar upp om användaren skriver in ett tal utanför valmenyn.
                        Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu 1 - 4");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");  //Estetisk för att användaren ska få ny rad innan meddelandet.
            Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu by using number 1 - 4\n" + e); //Aktiveras om användaren knappar in annat än heltal.
        }
    }
```

Comment: what exception should happen in case 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ScottPerham is correct that you cannot modify the collection while iterating it. Since you presumably want to erase only one item, you could also fix that by simply `break`ing out of the loop after you have removed the item.

This line has a problem:

```
if (item.Contains(erase))
```

`item` is an array of strings; the `Contains` method called is a method on the collection, which checks whether any elements in the collection match (exactly) the provided input. This is different from `string.Contains`, which looks for substrings. You want this instead:

```
if (item[0].Contains(erase))
```

**EDIT**

Given that your search string should be an exact match, you should find the post -- but you would also find any post where the body of the post is, say, "Log number: 2" (which could be a different post). You really want to check only `ítem[0]`.

---

To answer your second question: You already know how to find a post; you did that for the "delete" case. Once you've found the one you wish to change, just update the content, similar to what you do when creating a new post:

```
Console.Write("\tWhich log number do you want to change? : ");
string change = "Log number: " + Console.ReadLine();

foreach (string[] item in logBook)  // För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
{
    if (item[0].Contains(change))  // Om arr[0], arr[1] eller arr[2] innhåller sökord....,
    {
        string timeDate2 = time.ToLongDateString();  // Ger oss ett datum för inlägget.

        Console.Write("\tWrite a title to your post: ");
        string title2 = "Title: " + Console.ReadLine();  // Ger oss en titel för inlägget.

        Console.Write("\n\tPost is created " + timeDate2 + "\n\n\tWrite your post: ");

        string post2 = Console.ReadLine();

        item[1] = timeDate2;
        item[2] = title2;
        item[3] = post2;
    }
}
```

Please be aware that there is room for improvement in the structure of this code.

Comment: Thx Petter, I'll try this out and work with it as soon as I get my cup of coffee, I've been at it since early morning. I'll let u know the result.

Comment: I've tried it out and it works just great. I'm slowly learning this, it's only been 9 weeks yet ;)  Thx for help.

Comment: Lykke til videre.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the list while you are iterating over it in a foreach. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, **but can not be used to add or remove items** from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.

You could consider using a for loop rather than foreach? Something along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < logbook.Count; i++)
{
    if (logbook[i].Contains(erase))
    {
        logBook.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + erase + " is now removed from logbook.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for helping but why the i - - ;  ??

Comment: The i-- is to compensate for removing  an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RemoveAll instead:

```
logBook.RemoveAll(log => log.Any(row => row.Contains(erase)));
```

[List.RemoveAll Method @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: If (say) post #5 has a post body with the value "Log number: 2", it would be deleted along with the actual #2. `x[0].Contains(erase)` would be better.

Comment: I fail to find this requirement from the question. Also if x is empty that code would fail.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot modify the logBook collection while you are iterating over it with foreach. You can use a for loop to work backwards through the list and use RemoveAt when you find the post you are looking for.

Seeing as there can be at most one post with a given log number, you should also include a break in the loop to exit once the post has been found and removed. Something like this:

```
for (var i = logBook.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (logBook[i][0] == erase)
    {
        logBook.RemoveAt(i);
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + erase + " is now removed from logbook.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions: Pls understand that I'm new at coding but what exactly does "logBook[i][0]" refer to (What exactly does it mean. I'm in the belief that i got a list that contains elements of Array[] (type string), that in turn contains 4 elements of string (logNR, timeDate, post and title). All this like a tree (I'm trying to get the logic of it).

Why do the for-loop backwards?

Thx for helping